# How to join two cylinders with different inside diameters together as one?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm new to Blender. I need a part like this but I cannot find it ready made, so I decided to give it a try and do a 3D print. 
I made two cylinders with cylinders fill nothing and added the Solidify modifier. These two cylinders have the same outside diameter but different inside diameters. I want to join them together as one object. I tried select both and join, didn't work. It messed up the different diameters. Any one can advise how to do this properly?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try applying the modifiers individually then join the parts

Answer (score 2):

For this to work You have to **Apply the Solidify modifier** and then join the objects. Follow the steps below to accomplish this...

1. This is **almost** the copy of Your scene...

[image]

2. Now **both objects has the Solidify modifier applied** so they have a thickness as could be seen in edit mode here.

[image]

3. **Next step is to join both cylinders**. To do so select one and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when selecting the other - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to finish the process as shown below.

[image]

4. Now we have to **delete unnecessary faces** so select the part shown below and hit "X" selecting "Only Faces" option to delete them. Next image has this parts already deleted.

[image]

Next part **requires Loop Tools enabled** so enable it in the Preferences as shown below *(optionally Save User Setting to keep it enabled)*.

[image]

5. Now **select both inner Loops** shown below by using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Hold that key and click on one loop (between two vertices) to select the whole circle and then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and select the other one to **keep both selected like shown below**...

[image]

6. Now **join them using the Bridge function** (red rectangle) as show here...

[image]

7. **Select both outer loop and join them too** using Bridge again like below...

[image]

8. Switch to object mode and **YOU ARE DONE MATE - CONGRATS!** Just the final image of the object here...

[image]

Hope it helps You, Buddy.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos: Please dont edit my post next time. I have some writing-style and want to keep it that way ... in fact You are the only one I saw editing almost anything and anytime without the real need (no language or content mistakes). **I dont want this so please respect it - thank You in advance Duarte.**

Comment: Jan, you don't need to delete the unnecessary faces, you can select both rings and w > bridge and it will bridge

Comment: @Jan Matys If you dislike an edit or feel it changed the meaning of your answer you can revert it at any time. Please try to keep any extraneous text out of posts and use the suggested formatting

Comment: @moonboots: You are right mate but I thought that this way will be better for a beginner to practice and teach more things ... he could use both ways for sure.

Answer (score 1):

do this on edit mode: press [w] to display "specials" panel, bridge Edge Loop.

Comment: This answer is a pretty low-quality answer. A good answer should be precise and unambiguous.

Comment: it does the thing. still edited the answer to make it clearer.
"some peopple underapreciate the power of sintesis" :D

Comment: I know it might do the job but you need to at least put some effort into making it coherent. Why not showing some screenshots? Why not writing the steps down in a more understandable way?

Comment: its ok. You were right, i was choking. Ill have to get used to the stack interface itself. ill eventually get better. ;)